# Can capabilities for files be specified via cmake/cpack?

Tags: rpm, capabilities, cmake, deb

Since RPM 4.7, there has been the ability to specify that a file in an RPM package should be installed with [capabilities](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) set (via `%caps`).

Is there a way to specify something like this via `cmake`/`cpack` (preferably in a way that works for both RPM and Deb generators)?

Comment: It turns out that Deb packages don't support capabilities (I filed a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debhelper/+bug/1371695), so probably little point in pursuing this in cmake/cpack, and better to handle it in a postinstall script.